# Gif in launch screen

Tags: ios, swift

Im using this Class for gifs:

https://github.com/swiftgif/SwiftGif/blob/master/SwiftGifCommon/UIImage%2BGif.swift

But now, i want to add a gif to the launchscreen and since i can't set custom classes here, i don't know, how to do that. Any Ideas?

Comment: launch-screen is static, apart from the `xib` no class implementation will be loaded during launch (you cannot actually add any implementation to launch-screen) – but you can play any GIF anim after the `application(application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:) -> Bool` has returned and the main window (and its root-view-controller) has initiated – that is the first point in the app-lifecycle from when you can do such a thing.

Answer (score 4):

You can not use Custom classes in `Launchscreen`. Create a `UIViewController` and mark it as an `entry point`. Play the `gif` there and after a certain time you `perform a segue` to other `ViewController`. This little trick will work

**UPDATED**

In order to implement the logo animation we’ll need to do two things:

1. Add the first frame of the GIF as a static image in the launch screen
2. When the app launches add a view in the root view controller that
   loads the animated GIF at the same spot that we’ve put the static
   image in the launch screen

This way, when the app launches the user will get the impression that the launch screen is animating.

Have a look at [Animated launch screen using a GIF in iOS](https://www.amerhukic.com/animating-launch-screen-using-gif)

Comment: yeah but then i make the user wait longer to use the app. Is there no way to play a gif while loading the app?

Comment: @Ginso The launch screen is shown when the first view is not finish loading and the first view shown immediately after loaded. Even if the launch screen does ever support animated gif, your user still have to wait for the same gif data loading time before the launch screen shown since you must somehow load the data of the gif anyway. It won't be magically preloaded.

Comment: @RickyMo But loading the gif alone takes less time currently my react native app shows splash screen for 4 seconds in lower end devices. And I want to show animation in that. Its a very heavy app built by hundreds of devs and its not possible to reduce the load time further.